# They show me the empty Data Frame in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am try to print data into the data frame but they will me show that your data frame is empty how to solve these kindly  help in these matter

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers ={
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
    }
for page in range(1, 5):
    r =requests.get('https://www.redfin.com/city/5357/WA/Edmonds_={page}'.format(page=page))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    tra=soup.find_all('div',class_='bottomV2')
    productlinks=[]
    p=[]
    for links in tra:
        link=links.find('a',href=True)
        comp=link['href']
        abs_url = f'https://www.redfin.com{comp}'
        productlinks.append(abs_url)
        
    for link in productlinks:
        r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        price=soup.find('div',class_='statsValue').text
        p.append(price)
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':p})
print(df)
```

Comment: Please show the result data you're trying to get.

Comment: I am trying to get `price` from these website https://www.redfin.com/city/5357/WA/Edmonds

Comment: They're all in `class="homecardV2Price"` but redfin blocks your request as a robot, so you might want to use your headers as the deleted answer suggests, or if you're still blocked, adjust the headers or use Selenium/Pyppeteer or find an alternate approach. I recommend using `r.raise_for_status()` so you get a clear error right up front of what's going wrong with the request. If `res.ok` is false there's no point in proceeding with selectors or wondering why the df is empty; this tells you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: As an aside, declare `p=[]` outside of the loop, otherwise it'll be emptied on each fresh iteration. Best to start with 1 page, ensure that's working, then move to additional pages.